# Regex to DFA - How do I implement parsing preferences in regex search?

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I've tried a to implement a Regex to DFA converter, and it works, so far, but I don't understand how to implement "parsing preferences" in the DFA.

A classic example is $a^*$. This regex is ambiguous unlike $^\wedge a^*\\\$$, because given a string `aaaa`, we can accept `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, and `aaaa`.
Usually, the engine will say that $a^*$ is greedy or lazy, though I am unsure how this can be implemented in the DFA.

Another example is $a|a^*$, where the left side is a lazy/finite match, and the right side is a greedy match. If we prefer the left side, then we match `a` given the string `aaa`. If we prefer the right side, we match an empty string.

#### $a^*$ - Implementing Greediness

The minimal DFA to accepts this looks as follows:
[image: minimal DFA accepting a*]

My initial idea to implement greediness was to give **S** a flag which indicates that it's a "greedy termination state", making it match more `a`s if possible.
Does this work in general, or just this special case?
It handles this case correctly at least.

#### $a|a^*$ Implementing Union Preferences

A slightly optimized NFA looks as follows:
[image: NFA accepting `a|a*|]

**To give the developer more control, I want the left side of the union operator to be preferred.**
In the NFA, we do this easily by preferring to transition to **A** in the engine, and backtrack to **S** if we cannot accept.

How do I preserve this ability to disambiguate after constructing the DFA using union states?
After constructing a DFA with union states, we obtain:
[image]

`B|C` is the union of a greedy terminating state `B` and a lazy terminating state `C`.
In this case, it would be safe to mark `B|C` as lazy, so we would terminate immediately after accepting one `a`.

However, if our regex was $a^*|a$, then we would have constructed the same DFA, but the transformation would be wrong, because we have a preference for greedy termination instead.

How do you generally encode such parsing preferences for one side of a union in a DFA?

#### Edit - Attempted Formalization of Greediness

@yeputons has pointed out that insufficient formalization may be the problem, and they're on to something.
Academic DFAs are defined to terminate when we reach the end of our input. Success is then determined based on whether we are presently in a terminating state.

I have no idea how to formalize regex search though, which can stop in the middle of our input.

We can define laziness and greediness as follows:

> For a regex $A^*$, a greedy match of $A$ defines the rules $A'A\mapsto AA',\;\; A'\lnot A\mapsto\epsilon$
>
> For a regex $A^*$, a lazy match of $A$ defines the rule $A'\mapsto \epsilon\;|\;A'$

The definition of greedy matching is accepting more $A$ if the rule is also $A$, otherwise $\epsilon$.
This is a bad definition though, because it is not regular.
Also, we this definition doesn't work for $a^*a$, which requires us to match greedily, but not including the last `a`.

Is there a way to formalize greediness without a context-sensitive grammar?

Comment: I'd seek out for a formal definition of "regex" and "preferences" first. Academic regular expressions are relatively precisely defined and their basic forms don't have notions of `^`, `$`, "lazy", "greedy" or "match group", each (regex, string) pair is either a match or not. So if you're trying to change the set of matches, start with academic regular expressions from formal language theory, and gradually extend them. If you're trying to do something with group matches, I think there should be some papers on the topic.

Comment: For example, I'm not sure how to formally define "greezy" and "lazy" other than "the regex matches the shortest possible prefix of the haystack only" or something similar. But that can be handled by automaton's user, no need to alter automaton itself.

Comment: @yeputons formalization is the problem, I think you're onto something. Regex search works totally differently from regex matching, and I'm not even sure if you can formalize it using regular grammars.